# Should i avoid multi datacontext and migration configuration on code-first project?

Tags: entity-framework

I am working on a ASP.NET MVC 5.1 project, I would using the ASP.NET Identity feature and code first.

By default, the ASP.NET Identity having their own datacontext (**IdentityModels.cs**) which inherit **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext**.

Because i afraid to influence the Identity model.

So i create another context inherrit **DbContext** , and create another migration configuration by following command:

> enable-migrations **-ContextTypeName** PosApp.Models.OtherContext **-MigrationsDirectory**:OtherContextMigrations

And using specific configuration command line to update database:

> Add-Migration **-ConfigurationTypeName**
>   PosApp.OtherContextMigrations.Configuration **-Name** GenDB  Update-Database
>   **-ConfigurationTypeName** PosApp.OtherContextMigrations.Configuration

However, i found that it make the migration conflict between tables.

For example:

DataContext A and Configuration A:

Generate Table: **Blog** , **Post** , **Comment**

DataContext B and Configuration B:
Generate Table: **User**, but reference to **Blog** (1:N, that mean 1 user can have own multi blogs).

If i type command line - **add-migration** base on Config B.

The Blog table will be generate again, and conflict because the table exist on Config A.

Even i can override `OnModelCreating()` event and using `modelBuilder.ignore<T>` , but it resulting a mess.

So do i avoid multi config of migration?

Or any advantage on it?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track using moddelBuilder.ignore. In your identityDbContext add:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Ignore<Blog>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Then, to use your relationship from the User to the Blog, create a new data-context inheriting from IdentityDbContext and **don't**  add a migration to it.